# How to check whether the UITextfield is empty string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm trying to build a login page for an app. Something went wrong when testing the login condition.
There are two textfields, `username` and `password`. When the Login button is clicked, alert shows when

1) either fields are empty 
2) both filled.

The code reflects this below. But the result came out no matter that the textfield is empty or not, it only showed as textfields were filled ( only the else part run). So I assume there was something wrong with the if condition. But when I checked the if condition in other view, it worked.

Can anyone help?

```
if ([_pLoginIDField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_pPasswordField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yeah !" message:@"must complete all fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [error show];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *error2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oooops !" message:@"hhhhhhhhhh" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [error2 show];
}
```

Comment: If you `NSLog` both `UITextView.text` just before the `if`, what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (_pLoginIDField.text.length > 0 || _pPasswordField.text.length > 0)
```

Comment: The > 0 isn't even really necessary. You could just do
    
`if (_pLoginIDField.text.length || _pPasswordField.text.length)`

Comment: Thanks for help!! I tried  // if (_pLoginIDField.text.length == 0 || _pPasswordField.text.length == 0) // and the if condition worked.  Here comes another question. I test the if condition the way in the question above, is to test if the textfield.text is the same as the saved data in the key. I used NSUserDefaults to set and save the username and password. But when tried  [_pLoginID.text isEqualToString:[defaults objectForKey:@"username"] && [_pPassword.text isEqualToString:[defaults objectForKey:@"password"], it did not work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

NSString *text = [NSString stringWithString: nameUITextField.text];

if(text.length == 0){

}

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

you can count how many characters are in string, it is indirectly checking to null.

```
NSString *inputString = [NSString stringWithString: nameUITextField.text];

if(inputString.charachters.count == 0){
   // inputString is Blank 
   // Do your stuff

 }else{

 //inputString is not blank, Do other Stuff.
 }
```

the above condition satisfy if inputString is blank otherwise it will enter into else block.